# jQuery Promise with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I need one `setInterval` to start after another `setInterval` ends.  Is there a way to do this with promises?

Ideally, I would like the code to look something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
  setInterval(fun_1, 1000)
  //wait until this is done
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `setTimeout`? `setInterval` calls its callback endlessly, until `clearInterval` is called.

Comment: `setInterval(callback, n)` will repeat the provided `callback` every `n` milliseconds.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval vs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: setInterval will actually call your method `fun_1` till you use `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setInterval` calls the provided function after given interval of time until you `clear` its object. `So you do not need a loop for this`. You can `use a counter` to terminate it after counter reaches desired value.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/6Td4J/)**.

```
var myInter;
i = 1;
function fun_1()
{
   // some code
   if(i++==5)
      clearInterval(myInter);
}    

myInter = setInterval(fun_1, 1000);
```

Comment: @amoebe Could you please explain?

Comment: The title states "jQuery Promise" but not a single function of these was used: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ Although the question is super strange too.

Comment: Its was not me who gave title to question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you would like the second interval to begin the countdown after the previous interval is done?  In that case, you would say

```
window.setTimeout(fun_1, 1000);

function fun_1
{
    window.setTimeout(fun_2, 1000);
}
```

This starts the countdown for the second timeout after the first one has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the next interval after the first one completes

```
var cnt = 0;
function executeNextStep(){
    fun_1();
    if (cnt<5) {
        window.setTimeout(executeNextStep,1000);
    }
    cnt++;
}
executeNextStep();  //execute this right away
//window.setTimeout(executeNextStep,1000); use this if you want it to be delayed
```

if you need to execute different functions:

```
function fun_1() {
    console.log(1);
}
function fun_2() {
    console.log(2);
}
function fun_3() {
    console.log(3);
}

var fnc_stack = [fun_1, fun_2, fun_3];
var cnt = 0;
function executeNextStep(){
    fnc_stack[cnt]();
    cnt++;
    if (cnt<fnc_stack.length) {        
        window.setTimeout(executeNextStep,1000);
    }
}
executeNextStep();
```